# Problem turning on my radio

Tags: honda, audio, accord

Hello I had to replace my battery on my 2007 Honda Accord after I replaced it my radio won't turn on.

Comment: There is not much detail in this question but perhaps you need to unlock the radio with the radio code?

Comment: Have you looked in the handbook / pack for the code? If it is not there then a dealer may help or a search on the internet can be fruitful...

Comment: The code may also be on a nondescript white sticker located somewhere in your glove compartment area (should be noticeable when open).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I’ve found those stickers in the underhood fuse box as well.

Comment: How about the on/off button?